# How do I submit a form from a modal in react and then ensure that the data gets refreshed on the front end?

Tags: reactjs

my first question and also my first project in React. I have made good progress after spending tons of time on theory. Will quickly summarize.

1. I have a single button component on the front end. When I click the button I am opening a Modal component.
2. Inside the Modal component, I am using Formik. Using Props I am ensuring that the values from the NODE/MONGO backend are displayed correctly in the relevant text fields.
3. The idea is that the user can make whatever they choose to change and then hit Submit. On submit, I am connecting again to the NODE and updating the entry.
4. Now on Submit, the Modal also closes, I am now passing a function in useEffect and in that function fetching data again from the same collection and hoping to display the updated data.
5. After hitting the submit button once and then reopening the modal/form again I dont see the changes in the text box. However after closing the modal and then reopening again I see the changes have been saved.

Question - how can I get the changes to reflect in the form straight away ? Rather than waiting on the second click.

If I have asked a silly question please go easy on me as I ma just learning the whole React show :). Hoping someone can help me understand this.

Comment: I see your point but it's difficult to give a solve without seeing the implementation. Because you can do it in so many ways

Comment: Hey bud thanks. Can you explain a few ways you would do it. ? Maybe just 2 ways.

Comment: When asking questions it is best to include some code of your attempt so that it is possible to give feedback and provide possible solutions.

Comment: To refresh the view, update state with the current state without changes `this.setState({ state: this.state })` https://davidwalsh.name/react-force-render

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with a simple timeout. JUst delayed the execution of the function call with a setTimeout and that did the trick.